# Getting public functions using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have the following code where I am extracting all methods from a file.

```
var tree = file.GetSyntaxTreeAsync().Result;
var methodDeclarations = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();
```

How can I only get the public functions?

Comment: You need the semantic model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're looking for methods marked as public in the file, you can use the Modifiers property of MethodDeclarationSyntax objects like so:

```
        var publicMethods = root.DescendantNodes()
            .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
            .Where(method =>
                method.Modifiers.Where(modifier =>
                    modifier.Kind() == SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)
                .Any());
```

If you're intereseted in all the public method of a class declared in this file, you will need to heed @Slaks's advice and use the semantic model, as public methods declared in a parent class will not show up using only the syntax analysis.

Comment: How would you do it with the semantic model? AFAICT it only gives you the `DeclaredAccessibility`, which isn't enough (e.g. it will classify interface method implementations as "private")